# Find name of node associated with maximum degree in igraph data frame

Tags: r, igraph

I am using the *igraph* package to find degree of each node (the built in `degree(g)` function) and it returns a numeric vector. How can I tell which node has the maximum degree (not the value but the node name)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a igraph data frame `G`, then you can create a TRUE/FALSE vector with `degree(G)==max(degree(G))`. You can then use that to find the name of the node(s) that meet that criteria - `V(G)$name[degree(G)==max(degree(G))]`.

I created a small example to illustrate:

```
library(igraph)
df = data.frame(node1=c("Bob", "Jim", "Dave", "Dave"),
                node2=c("Jane", "John", "Sally", "Al"))

G = graph.data.frame(df)
V(G)$name[degree(G)==max(degree(G))]
[1] "Dave"
```

Comment: Used it like this:  V(G)$name[degree(G,mode="out")==max(degree(G,mode="out"))]

Answer (score 2):

Example data

```
dat<-sample(0:100,100,rep=FALSE)
maximum<-dat[order(dat,decreasing = TRUE)
```

Verify

```
maximum
```